# Python TypeError: missing 2 required positional arguments // How can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, typeerror

I have this `TypeError: capture_and_decode() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'bitrange' and 'axes'`

My code is this one:

```
def capture_and_decode(self, bitrange, axes):
    cam_width, cam_height = self.camera.resolution
    scr_range = self.display.displaywindow.resolution
    self.raw_images = numpy.empty((len(axes), cam_height, cam_width, bitrange))

    for axis in axes:

       for bits in range(0,bitrange):
           stripe_width = cam_width // 2 ** (bits + 1)
           print(stripe_width)
           binary = numpy.fromiter(GrayCode(bits + 1).generate_gray(), dtype=numpy.int) % 2
           vector = numpy.repeat(binary, stripe_width)
           img = numpy.tile(vector, (cam_height, 1))

       self.display.displaywindow.show(img)  
       time.sleep(0.25)
       self.raw_images[axis, :, :, bits] = self.camera.capture()
```

the error is in the last line.

Comment: Where do you call `capture_and_decode(..)`? Could you share that part of your code?

Comment: When you *called* the function you didn't supply: *2 required positional arguments*. You also need to post the error message Python shows you because in the snippet you provided no calls to `capture_and_decode` are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code looks like this:

```
obj.capture_and_decode()
```

The first argument (`self`) is supplied for you, but you need to account for the other two

If they are optional, change your function definition to include defaults, for example:

```
def capture_and_decode(self, bitrange=10, axes=[])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `capture_and_decode()` method is designed to take two positional arguments; namely a bitrange and axes. Wherever you're calling this method, you need to provide these arguments as such:

```
 cam = CameraClass()
 cam.capture_and_decode(500, 4) # or whatever the values should be.
```